# SVG:hover to not change children strokes

Tags: css, svg

When :hover parent I want to change only the parent stroke, not the childrens.
https://codepen.io/gloreau/pen/OJWPeod

```
.artistNode {
  stroke-width: 2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.artistNode:hover {
        stroke: red;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        stroke-width: 2;
}
```

I want only to change the rectangle border not the childrens.

Comment: Move the text outside the group. Also the corect url is https://codepen.io/gloreau/pen/OJWPeod

Comment: or change the selector to #Rectangle_1-2:hover

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure moving the text outside the composant is a good thing in term of semantic. I tried to apply it on rectangle the problem is when I do if the mouse is hover the text the hover won't work.

Comment: Use `.artistNode:hover text` to apply a different formatting to those elements?

Comment: apply pointer-events: none to the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to style only the `<rect>` when the parent is hovered, the selector is

```css
.artistNode:hover rect
```

```css
.artistNode {
  stroke-width: 2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.artistNode:hover rect {
  stroke: red;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="327" height="108" viewBox="0 0 327 108">
  <defs>
    <filter id="Rectangle_1" x="0" y="0" width="327" height="108" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Jeffrey_Watts" data-name="Jeffrey Watts" transform="translate(9 6)" class="artistNode">
    <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -9, -6)" filter="url(#Rectangle_1)">
      <rect id="Rectangle_1-2" data-name="Rectangle 1" width="309" height="90" rx="5" transform="translate(9 6)" fill="#fff"/>
    </g>
    <text id="Jeffrey_Watts-2" data-name="Jeffrey Watts" transform="translate(108 17)" fill="#300d65" font-size="20" font-family="Nunito-Regular, Nunito"><tspan x="0" y="20">Jeffrey Watts</tspan></text>
    <text id="_1969_-" data-name="1969 -" transform="translate(108 50)" fill="#242424" font-size="16" font-family="OpenSans-Regular, Open Sans"><tspan x="0" y="17">1969 -</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

If you wanted to style all elements but the rect, you could use `:not()`

```css
.artistNode {
  stroke-width: 2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.artistNode:hover :not(rect) {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="327" height="108" viewBox="0 0 327 108">
  <defs>
    <filter id="Rectangle_1" x="0" y="0" width="327" height="108" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Jeffrey_Watts" data-name="Jeffrey Watts" transform="translate(9 6)" class="artistNode">
    <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -9, -6)" filter="url(#Rectangle_1)">
      <rect id="Rectangle_1-2" data-name="Rectangle 1" width="309" height="90" rx="5" transform="translate(9 6)" fill="#fff"/>
    </g>
    <text id="Jeffrey_Watts-2" data-name="Jeffrey Watts" transform="translate(108 17)" fill="#300d65" font-size="20" font-family="Nunito-Regular, Nunito"><tspan x="0" y="20">Jeffrey Watts</tspan></text>
    <text id="_1969_-" data-name="1969 -" transform="translate(108 50)" fill="#242424" font-size="16" font-family="OpenSans-Regular, Open Sans"><tspan x="0" y="17">1969 -</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And if you wanted to select only a few elements, you could combine multiple selectors:

```css
.artistNode {
  stroke-width: 2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.artistNode:hover #_1969_-, .artistNode:hover #Jeffrey_Watts-2 {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="327" height="108" viewBox="0 0 327 108">
  <defs>
    <filter id="Rectangle_1" x="0" y="0" width="327" height="108" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="Jeffrey_Watts" data-name="Jeffrey Watts" transform="translate(9 6)" class="artistNode">
    <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -9, -6)" filter="url(#Rectangle_1)">
      <rect id="Rectangle_1-2" data-name="Rectangle 1" width="309" height="90" rx="5" transform="translate(9 6)" fill="#fff"/>
    </g>
    <text id="Jeffrey_Watts-2" data-name="Jeffrey Watts" transform="translate(108 17)" fill="#300d65" font-size="20" font-family="Nunito-Regular, Nunito"><tspan x="0" y="20">Jeffrey Watts</tspan></text>
    <text id="_1969_-" data-name="1969 -" transform="translate(108 50)" fill="#242424" font-size="16" font-family="OpenSans-Regular, Open Sans"><tspan x="0" y="17">1969 -</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answers the post.
Kaiido this is perfect I understand it all now, thank so much for your time.

Comment: @Warry You can also thank using upvote (upper gray rectangle near the answer number)